# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver in Maven project

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to connect to a SQLServer DB using JDBC. I'm using jre 1.6 and I've added the 'sqljdbc/jar' to my class path on my OS. I've also added that jar far to my build path. When my code hits this line
`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");`
it explodes. I can navigate to the class in the package explorer, I can also type out the namespace and eclipse intellisense picks it up as well, yet when it loads I get
`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`.
I'm using Eclipse Indigo Release 2 w/ Spring STS plugin, can any one tell me whats going on? btw: I can connect to my db using the DB using DB Explorer in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you eveyrone for your suggestions, here is how I solved it:

1. I added the jar in question to my `.m2` repository folder
2. Opened `Pom.xml` => clicked `Dependencies` Tab => clicked `Add`
3. Modeled a folder structure to match that of that of the attributes that I entered. For example `jdbc\sqljdbc4\4\sqljdbc4-0.jar` (I added `-0` as it needs to have a version #)*
4. Rebuild, Deploy and BAM!

Answer (score 0):

Try to see if you have another jar file sqljdbc2.jar in the same location. Use that one.
Also you may want to try jTDS driver for SQL server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have more than one library referencing `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver`, Check your driver or alternatively, try downloading a different version.

Sometimes doing a clean and build helps ( Project->Clean) , then build again might help.

Good luck

PB